# edit Active Directory site location Powershell

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to change the site in my AD via PowerShell.
So far I have no issues with the name or the description, but keep getting errors when trying to change the location of the site.

The code which keeps giving errors:

```
Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).ConfigurationNamingContext -filter "objectclass -eq 'site'" | Set-ADObject -Properties location.location
Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).ConfigurationNamingContext -filter "objectclass -eq 'site'" | Set-ADObject -Location "SiteLocation"
```

Comment: First, what errors are you getting? Second, there's no `-Properties` or `-Location` parameter for `Set-ADObject`, so maybe check the [MSDN page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852326(v=wps.630).aspx) to make sure you're using it properly. In fact, there's even an example there that shows how to add a site to a property for an object.

Comment: the error I am receiving is `Set-ADObject : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Properties'.
At line:4 char:118
+ ... | Set-ADObject -Properties location).location
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADObject], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADObject`

I use a similar code to change the description (where -Properties is -Description) which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is wrong:

```
... location.location <--
```

Also Set-ADObject does not have a parameter "-Location".

It's better to use built in cmdlets to work with AD Sites:

```
Get-ADReplicationSite YOUR_SITE_NAME | Set-ADReplicationSite -Replace @{ "location" = "YOUR_LOCATION" }
```

It's much easier and cleaner.